# Initializing RedisHttpSessionConfiguration with Spring Session Data Redis

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis, spring-session

I am trying to replace the default JDBC session management in my Spring application with Redis, using Spring Session Data Redis 2.2.2.RELEASE and Jedis 3.10.0 on Java 11.
However, I am getting the following error on application startup:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in RedisHttpSessionConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection.getConfig(java.lang.String)'
```

I have tried various version combinations of the dependencies but get the same error. This seems to be related to some incompatibility between Spring Session Data Redis and the Jedis client.
Has anyone encountered this error before when setting up Redis HTTP session management with Spring? Any tips on how to resolve it?

Using different session data redis versions and jedis client versions

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? What Spring Framework version are you using?

Comment: Nope, just spring no boot. Spring version is 5.3.22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Session Data Redis 2.2.2.RELEASE is not currently supported anymore and I don't think that the version of Spring Data Redis that is uses is compatible with Jedis 3.10.0. Furthermore, that version of Spring Session is not compatible with  Spring Framework 5.3.22.

Try using the latest version compatible with Spring Framework 5.3.22, like so:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2021.2.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I have tried this and the problem is still the same. I looked under the hood of spring session bom and found out that it pulls in spring session data redis 2.7.4 which I have tried in the past and didn't fix the issue. Is there something else to do?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible sample?

Comment: Here is my pom with the distribution and repository taken out:
https://pastebin.com/Kt8taupP